# Proving the number of renewals

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$\{X_n, n\geq 1\}$ is an iid sequence of non-negative r.v., with $0<E(X_n)<\infty$

Let $N(t)$ be the number of renewals in $[0,t]$. In Resnick's Probability Path, on page 223, he states

> We need to show $N(t)\xrightarrow{}\infty$ as $t\xrightarrow{}\infty$, and because of monotonicity, it suffices to show $N(t)\xrightarrow{P}\infty$.

Why is that? We know that $N(t)$ is non-decreasing in $t$, but how can $\forall_mP(\{\omega: N(t,\omega)>m\})\xrightarrow[t\rightarrow \infty]{} 1$ imply $N(t,\omega)\xrightarrow[]{a.s.}\infty$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the monotonicity of a measure. Fix any positive $m$, then:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\lim N(t) \ge m) = \mathbb{P}(\exists \ t \ | \  N(t) \ge m) \ge \mathbb{P}(N(t_0) \ge m)
$$
for any choice of $t_0$. Now passing to the limit over $t_0$ gives the result.

Comment: thanks. I've edited my question,since I had read the text wrong... Either way, you've helped me understand what I need. ;)